# Video source is not playing in html video tag

Tags: html, html5-video

I have some video sources as I stated below

Sample Video Source: https://r1---sn-5hne6nsr.c.2mdn.net/videoplayback/id/be1889e136a157dd/itag/37/source/doubleclick_dmm/ctier/L/acao/yes/ip/0.0.0.0/ipbits/0/expire/3747290803/sparams/acao,ctier,expire,id,ip,ipbits,itag,mh,mip,mm,mn,ms,mv,mvi,pl,source/signature/388EE84E16EB00C9F843F9A73533592875F7AC21.4849C933939EDFCC5C988E8F948B2DACD1A5505E/key/cms1/cms_redirect/yes/mh/NQ/mip/83.162.138.194/mm/42/mn/sn-5hne6nsr/ms/onc/mt/1609252593/mv/m/mvi/1/pl/14/file/file.mp4

When I copied and pasted in the browser it is working seamlessly but when I give it to an HTML Video tag like below, it does not work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
 <html> 
  <body> 
   <video controls="" autoplay="" name="media">
    <source src="https://r1---sn-5hne6nsr.c.2mdn.net/videoplayback/id/be1889e136a157dd/itag/37/source/doubleclick_dmm/ctier/L/acao/yes/ip/0.0.0.0/ipbits/0/expire/3747290803/sparams/acao,ctier,expire,id,ip,ipbits,itag,mh,mip,mm,mn,ms,mv,mvi,pl,source/signature/388EE84E16EB00C9F843F9A73533592875F7AC21.4849C933939EDFCC5C988E8F948B2DACD1A5505E/key/cms1/cms_redirect/yes/mh/NQ/mip/83.162.138.194/mm/42/mn/sn-5hne6nsr/ms/onc/mt/1609252593/mv/m/mvi/1/pl/14/file/file.mp4" type="video/mp4">
   </video>
  </body> 
</html>
```

What am I missing? Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out why your video tag was not playing, run your HTML with all your browser  extensions off, The video tag is being blocked by my adblocker. After I turned it off it was working as regular.

The reason behind it because adblockers run in a privileged mode, their operation does not trigger events in the nonprivileged script space.

To work around it you have to [Detect adblockers](https://www.google.com/search?safe=strict&q=javascript+detect+adblock).

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, after turning it off, it worked.